# How to join the atributes of xml file into a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have to join all the same atributes of a parsed XML file into an `NSMubableDictionary`.

I need everything about **"show1", "show2"**, etc... in a dictionary (being "**"show1", "show2"**, etc... the keys, and the atributes being `NSArrays` belonging to each key.

I'm using the RaptureXML library to parse the content:

```
RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLString:string
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//audio" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *program) {

    NSString * show = [NSString stringWithString:[program attribute:@"program"]];
    NSString * date = [NSString stringWithString:[program attribute:@"date"]];
    NSString * time = [NSString stringWithString:[program attribute:@"time"]];
    NSString * path = [NSString stringWithString:[program attribute:@"path"]];

}];
```

}

Here is the XML file:

```
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="12:00 to 13:00" program="show1" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_12.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="11:00 to 12:00" program="show2" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_11.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="10:00 to 11:00" program="show2" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_10.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="09:00 to 10:00" program="show2" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_09.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="08:00 to 09:00" program="show3" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_08.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="07:00 to 08:00" program="show3" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_07.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="06:00 to 07:00" program="show3" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_06.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="05:00 to 06:00" program="show4" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_05.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="04:00 to 05:00" program="show4" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_04.mp3"/>
<audio date="11/01/2012" time="03:00 to 04:00" program="show4" path="http://mydomain/onDemand/audio_03.mp3"/>
```

How can I do this? Is there a better way to approach this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no hint from you about what XML lib you are using, some pseudocode:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = blablah
for(xmlthing * audio in yourxmlarrayofthoseaudiotags)
{
    NSString * key = [audio attributeForKey:@"program"];
    NSArray * showObject = [dict objectForKey:key];
    if(showObject == nil)
    {
        create your base array/dictionary object based on shows
    }
    create your show dictionary object by adding only date, time, path
    [showObject addObject:showtime];
}
```

Edit:
Its a good thing you mention the lib as that one is block based and completely different than all other xml libs. The above code was pseudocode, you have to update and change the things necessary to get it working in your code. But anyway, for RaptureXML something along the lines of:

```
NSMutableDictionary * reorgDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[rootXML iterate:@"audio.*" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement * element) {
     NSString * key = [element attribute:@"program"];
     NSMutableArray * showObjects = [reorgDict objectForKey:key];
    if(showObjects == nil)
    {
        showObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [reorgDict setObject:showObjects forKey:key];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary * thisShow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [thisShow setObject:element attribute:@"date" forKey:@"date"];
    [thisShow setObject:element attribute:@"time" forKey:@"time"];
    [thisShow setObject:element attribute:@"path" forKey:@"path"];
    [showObjects addObject:thisShow];
}];
```

There may be a more clever way to do the processing part there but I've not used this library before. But what the above code is trying to do is reparse the xml and put it into a structure like the below

```
>dictionary
\-> key = "program" ("show1")
 \-> array
  \-> dictionary
    \-> key = "date"
    \-> key = "time"
    \-> key = "path"

\-> key = "program" ("show2")
 \-> array
  \-> dictionary
    \-> key = "date"
    \-> key = "time"
    \-> key = "path"
  \-> dictionary
    \-> key = "date"
    \-> key = "time"
    \-> key = "path"
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! Right now I've pasted the code for parsing the XML, using the RaptureXML library. How would I implement your pseudocode inside the block? I tried but I'm getting an infinite loop. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `NSXMLParser`, check it [out](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There is a good document about it by Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using an open source library to parse the XML content. I'm just having a hard time joining the attributes after the parsing is done.

Comment: I suggest you post more info. What library is it? Seeing some of the code wouldn't hurt either.